# How to set the position of groups in a Seurat object on a FeatureHeatmap plot

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, ggplot2

I am analysing singe cell sequence data and I have followed this tutorial, https://satijalab.org/seurat/pbmc3k_tutorial.html to perform QC and various differential analyses using the Seurat package on my data up till now.

How can I rearrange on the resulting plot, the order in which the groups of my samples appear when I use the `FeatureHeatmap()` function to visualise the differential gene expression of Gene1 and Gene2 across the cell clusters?

```
FeatureHeatmap(object = object, features.plot = c("Gene1", "Gene2"), 
               group.by = "Conditions",
               pt.size = 0.25, key.position = "top",
               max.exp = 3)
```

produces:
[image]

but I want:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible in Seurat v2, but in v3 you can change the factor levels of the grouping variable to change the plot order:

```
library(Seurat)

FeaturePlot(object = pbmc_small,
            features = head(VariableFeatures(pbmc_small), 2),
            split.by = 'groups')
```

[image]

Change the order:

```
pbmc_small$groups <- factor(pbmc_small$groups, levels = c('g2', 'g1'))

FeaturePlot(object = pbmc_small,
            features = head(VariableFeatures(pbmc_small), 2),
            split.by = 'groups')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However the function `VariableFeatures` is not present in my Seurat package. I get the error: `Error in VariableFeatures(object) : 
  could not find function "VariableFeatures"` **@TimStuart**

Comment: Yes, that function is part of Seurat v3. This answer will only work for v3

Comment: How do I get the Seurat V3 package? My computer is having issue downloading it automaticaally, so I wish to download the Seurat V3 package manually and then load it. Thanks. **@TimStuart**

Comment: Will it also be advisable that I move to Seurat V3 at this level or I may need to restart my analyses afresh and repeat all steps with Seurat V3?

Comment: You can install v3 using devtools: `devtools::install_github(repo = 'satijalab/seurat', ref = 'release/3.0')`. I don't know how much effort it is for you to repeat analyses with Seurat v3, but you can also just update the Seurat object using `UpdateSeuratObject`. See here for more information: https://satijalab.org/seurat/essential_commands.html

Comment: I obtain this: `devtools::install_github(repo = 'satijalab/seurat', ref = 'release/3.0')` : `package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked:
Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘curl’`. `UpdateSeuratObject(object):
Object representation is consistent with the most current Seurat version.`   
The `FeatureHeatmap()` actually uses the alphabetical order of the conditions which I provided in the metadata slot. Is there a possibility to reorder the factor levels without harming the integrity of the data in the Seurat object?

Comment: Can you confirm Seurat v3 has actually been installed and loaded before running `UpdateSeuratObject`?